# If I eat you and you eat me

Tags: riddle, word

If I eat you, you might eat me and then you won't ever be hungry again.
If I eat you and you don't eat me, you might have dressed up for me.
If I eat half of you, I might not be very tall.
If I don't eat you when you eat me, I'm small, but not as small as when I fall.
If neither of us eats the other, I will still be waiting for you in your bathroom.
I'm a serial killer.
But you like me.

Who am I?

Comment: That's a lovely riddle!!

Comment: I think it's a parallel killer.

Comment: Hey, I followed a link to this question expecting something completely different than a riddle!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that you are

> Water

If I eat you, you might eat me and then you won't ever be hungry again.

> If you are submerged in water and drinking it in you are probably drowning so will soon never be hungry again.

If I eat you and you don't eat me, you might have dressed up for me.

> If you are submerged in water but not drinking it then it indicates you have planned to swim or scuba dive, so will be appropriately dressed.

If I eat half of you, I might not be very tall.

> If only half submerged, you must be standing or sitting in shallow water.

If I don't eat you when you eat me, I'm small, but not as small as when I fall.

> Water you drink comes in larger portions than when it falls (rain).

If neither of us eats the other, I will still be waiting for you in your bathroom.

> Water waits in the pipes and toilet of the bathroom.

I'm a serial killer.

> Many people have drowned and continue to do so.

But you like me.

> We all like to drink water in some form.

Comment: If this is the answer, I think the rot(onguebbz) bit gave it away.